# What is appropriate for creating a booking system?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications

I need a booking system for a theoretical project website. It would be an in-house job (not outsourcing to a web service) but all google searches on the subject yield results for said web services.

I'd want to be able to use the system as such:
For each day, there is availability recorded and if available a user can book in using the website, which sets that date to unavailable. There are other complexities, but this is the basic system I am trying to achieve - what would allow me to implement something like this?

Comment: Booking for what? Appointment-keeping? Events at clubs? Hotel rooms?

Answer (score 0):

This has a "free" category, but is slightly restricted: http://www.hitappoint.com/ (there's a paid-for version with more feature).

Another good (non-free) option: http://www.schedule-organizer.de/en/

Comment: It's not due to cost, but I'd prefer not to be outsourcing this.

Comment: @Joe - Both of those scripts install on YOUR server.